# difference between 2 columns (array of strings) and show where the difference is

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a query to capture Comments by teachers from two different databases. The teachers are adding comments to the front end and they are sent to two different databases. I am able to show the comments for the student for a subject from both the databases. But, I also have to find the minor differences between the two comments coming from both the databases.

I am so far able to compare the two columns (containing the teachers comments). and show null if the two columns are the same. But, I am not able to show where the difference between the two column values is.

```
Select distinct t1.SStudentID as SStudent, t2.AStudentId as AStudent , t1.Result as Result1,  t2.EnteredValue as Result2,
  COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.Result COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI, t2.EnteredValue COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI),NULLIF(t2.EnteredValue COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI, t1.Result COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI)) as NULL_IF_SAME
 from
 (SELECT  distinct r.ID as SStudentID,r.ClassCode,r.TopicComment as Result
  FROM [Database1].[dbo].[StudentAssessmentMarkBook] r
   where r.classcode like '9%' and r.TopicComment != ''
  ) t1
  join
  (SELECT  distinct a.Code as AStudentId ,c.code as ClassCode, ar.EnteredValue
  FROM [Database2].[dbo].[AssessmentItem] a
  join [Database2].[dbo].[ClassGroup] c on c.SubjectId=a.SubjectId
  join [Database2].[dbo].[Result] ar on ar.AssessmentItemId = a.Id
  where c.code like '9%' and a.code like '%COM%') t2 on (t1.ClassCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = t2.code COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI )
   where (t1.SStudentID = t2.AStudentId)
```

I now want to show the difference between Result1 and Result2 columns and display in new column where the difference is.